# Function called before filling $scope array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem with AngularJS and a function that is called before data array being filled. When my function is called in `ng-init`, the `$scope.bookings` array hasn't been evaluated (filled with data), resulting in no data.

**My goal is to:** Get all bookings for a certain bookingType and a certain date, and display all of them in a `<td>`

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GpjemTI.png]

---

**Here is my HTML code:**

*Description:* I loop through all `bookingTypes` and then through all `dates`. The `ng-init` is executed as many times as the dates are, and that works. `otherBookings` should be an array of bookings for that bookingType and that date. However, `$scope.bookings` hasn't been filled with data, so `otherBookings` loop is never executed.

```
<tr ng-repeat="bookingType in bookingTypes">
    <td>{{bookingType.Name}}]</td>
    <td ng-repeat="date in dates" ng-init="otherBookings = checkOtherBookings(bookingType.ID, date)">
        <span ng-repeat="otherBooking in otherBookings">
            <a ng-href="/Bookings/Edit/{{otherBooking.Booking.ID}}"><span >{{otherBooking.Customer.FirstName}}</span></a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

*Description:* In top of the `BookingsController` I call a service which fills the `$scope.bookings` array with data and the `$scope.checkOtherBookings()` function is below that:

```
BookingService.getAllBookings().then(function(data) {
    $scope.bookings = data.data;
});

$scope.checkOtherBookings = function(bookingType, date) {
    console.log($scope.bookings);

    var newBookingArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.bookings.length; i++) {
        if($scope.bookings[i].Booking.Type == bookingType) {
            var tmpDateFrom = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateFrom;
            var tmpDateTo = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateTo;
            if(date >= tmpDateFrom && date <= tmpDateTo) {
                newBookingArray.push($scope.bookings[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return newBookingArray;
};
```

The `$scope.checkOtherBookings()` function is called **22 times** (as many times as the dates are), but the `console.log($scope.bookings)` is outputting **22 times** `[]` - so my observation is that `$scope.bookings` array is empty every time the function is called.

I need some kind of a method to wait to execute the `ng-init` until the `$scope.bookings` array is filled with data.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE 1 - 14.09.13**

Now `newBookingArray` has some data but `otherBookings` in `ng-init` never gets them.

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="bookingType in bookingTypes">
    <td>{{bookingType.Name}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="date in dates" ng-init="otherBookings = checkOtherBookings(bookingType.ID, date)">
        <span ng-repeat="otherBooking in otherBookings">
            <a ng-href="/Bookings/Edit/{{otherBooking.Booking.ID}}"><span >{{otherBooking.Customer.FirstName}}</span></a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
BookingService.getAllBookings().then(function(data) {
    $scope.bookings = data.data;
});

$scope.checkOtherBookings = function(bookingTypeID, date) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.$watch('bookings', function(bookings) {
        if(!bookings.length) return;
        var newBookingArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.bookings.length; i++) {
            if($scope.bookings[i].Booking.Type == bookingTypeID) {
                var tmpDateFrom = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateFrom;
                var tmpDateTo = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateTo;
                if(date >= tmpDateFrom && date <= tmpDateTo) {
                    newBookingArray.push($scope.bookings[i]);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(newBookingArray));
                }
            }
        }

        deferred.resolve(newBookingArray);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

---

**UPDATE 2 - 14.09.13**

This is resolved! I moved the assignment from `ng-init` to the `ng-repeat` and it works perfectly.

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="bookingType in bookingTypes">
    <td>{{bookingType.Name}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
        <span ng-repeat="otherBooking in checkOtherBookings(bookingType.ID, date)">
            <a ng-href="/Bookings/Edit/{{otherBooking.Booking.ID}}"><span >{{otherBooking.Customer.FirstName}}</span></a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
BookingService.getAllBookings().then(function(data) {
    $scope.bookings = data.data;
});

$scope.checkOtherBookings = function(bookingTypeID, date) {
    var newBookingArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.bookings.length; i++) {
        if($scope.bookings[i].Booking.Type == bookingTypeID) {
            var tmpDateFrom = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateFrom;
            var tmpDateTo = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateTo;
            if(dateInRange(tmpDateFrom, tmpDateTo, date)) {
                newBookingArray.push($scope.bookings[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return newBookingArray;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a promise inside `checkOtherBookings`. AngularJS parser automatically deals with promises. So your code would look like this:

```
$scope.checkOtherBookings = function(bookingType, date) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.$watch('bookings', function(bookings) {
        if (!bookings) return;
        var newBookingArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.bookings.length; i++) {
            if($scope.bookings[i].Booking.Type == bookingType) {
                var tmpDateFrom = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateFrom;
                var tmpDateTo = $scope.bookings[i].Booking.DateTo;
                if(date >= tmpDateFrom && date <= tmpDateTo) {
                    newBookingArray.push($scope.bookings[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        deferred.resolve(newBookingArray);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I've created a plunker that demonstrates the technique here: [demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/krzZxP5feWrXHW1IKN3d?p=preview).

**Updated:**

The above approach works for AngularJS 1.0.x. The parser of AngularJS 1.2RC (and possibly 1.1.x) handles function returning promise differently, specifically it doesn't return the promise but immediately returning the internal `$$v` of the promise, which is `undefined` because it's not yet resolved. If you use 1.2, I suggest get rid of `ng-init` and try one of the approaches below.

Approach #1:

```
$scope.$watch('bookings', function(bookings) {
    if (!bookings) return;
    // filter bookings, then set $scope.otherBookings = filteredList
});
```

Approach #2:

```
$scope.getOtherBookings = function() {
   // return filter list here
}

<span ng-repeat="otherBooking in getOtherBookings()">
```

Approach #3:

```
<span ng-repeat="otherBooking in bookings | customFilterFunction">
```

Comment: This works well when I `console.log($scope.bookings)` and get some data, but in the HTML/view nothing appears.

Comment: When pushing into newBookingArray, I tried `console.log(newBookingArray)`. I get 5 objects, however they never make it to the view. Something wrong with this:
`<span ng-repeat="otherBooking in otherBookings">`

Comment: `$scope.otherBookings` is always undefined. Like it doesn't get assigned.

Comment: Then you have a second problem. You should examine the plunker I post (which shows a sample use case) and check how your code structure is different. Otherwise, posting another question (if possible, include a plunker or jsfiddle).

Comment: I duplicated the scenario and it works fine. But I can't possibly see what's wrong with my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0GdnVgicVXav7L0dlBIy?p=preview

Comment: Your example contains bug (multiply 2 to the object -> NaN). See the updated which works for both types of arrays: http://plnkr.co/edit/t37APSYDLXGfFZTzhRG0?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I found out after I posted the comment. :-) But I'm not getting my code to work. Gonna update the post. Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: What version of AngularJS you use?

Comment: lol. I just read the 1.2rc parser source & find out it handles promise differently from 1.0.7 (the one used in the plunker). See my updated answer.

Comment: God bless you. I changed my `checkOtherBookings()` function to the previous one (without the watch), and changed HTML to: `<span ng-repeat="otherBooking in checkOtherBookings(bookingType.ID, date)">` and it **WORKS GREAT!**